# How can I get the path without the filename in Windows using Perl?

Tags: windows, perl, filenames

I am looking to get the path without the filename in windows through perl

I have the full path like this:

`c:\My_Designs\ipcore_script\test\src\IP_CORE\mux\sus.do`

I need only the path and want to strip off the filename like:

`c:\My_Designs\ipcore_script\test\src\IP_CORE\mux`

Answer (score 7):

Use [File::Basename](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Basename)

```
> perl -MFile::Basename -wE "say dirname(qq(c:/perl/bin/perl.exe));"
c:/perl/bin
```

Comment: File::Spec is another option.  (I switched from File::Basename to File::Spec a couple of years ago; I'll follow up if I remember why I did that.)

Comment: @KeithThompson `NOTE: File::Basename's dirname() and basename() emulate the behaviours, and quirks, of the shell and C functions of the same name. If your concern is just parsing paths it is safer to use File::Spec's splitpath() and splitdir() methods.`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use [Path::Class](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Path::Class):

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Path::Class;

my $file = file('c:\My_Designs\ipcore_script\test\src\IP_CORE\mux\sus.do');

print $file->parent, "\n";
```

Output:

```
C:\My_Designs\ipcore_script\test\src\IP_CORE\mux
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for solution but I get this error. Can't locate Path/Class.pm in @INC (@INC contains: C:/Perl64/site/lib C:/Perl64/
lib .) at script.pl line 6.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at script.pl line 6. Where I can find this class.pm library

Comment: @mitt2050 There is a link in his answer. If you use ActivePerl, however, you can use their package manager. From the cmd prompt, simply type `ppm install Path::Class`. Or just `ppm` to access the GUI.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
$path='c:\My_Designs\ipcore_script\test\src\IP_CORE\mux\sus.do';

my $pathname=substr($path, 0, rindex($path,"\\"));

Result:
c:\My_Designs\ipcore_script\test\src\IP_CORE\mux
```